# Disabling Button from different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong nothing happens when the methods are called.

Declared in the interface of the class

```
ViewController* mainMenu;

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {

    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        mainMenu = [[ViewController alloc] init];

        ....
    }
}

- (void)pauseEnabled {
    //  mainMenu.pauseButton.hidden = NO;
    //  mainMenu.pauseButton.enabled = YES;
    [mainMenu.pauseButton setHidden:NO];
    [mainMenu.pauseButton setEnabled:YES];
}

- (void)pauseDisabled {
    mainMenu.pauseButton.hidden = YES;
    mainMenu.pauseButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)startGame {
    [self pauseEnabled];
    ......
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't name your mainMenu view controller class "`ViewController`".  Why not something much more intuitive, like "`MainMenuViewController`" or "`MainViewController`"?

Comment: A view controller should control its own view... hence its name...

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
mainMenu = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

you're creating a new view controller whose view isn't loaded and which is never shown on screen. You need to get an instance of `ViewController` which is actually presented on screen so that you can send it messages. How you do that depends very much on the structure of your app and what creates the `ViewController`.

Your usage of `initWithSize:` indicates that this object isn't a controller itself. In this case you may want to rethink what you're doing and, rather than have this class maintain a reference to a view controller, instead pass it a reference to the button that it should interact with when it is created.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `pauseButton` is wired to the outlet in the storyboard / xib file. Basically, make sure it is not `nil`. Also verify if you are adding the `mainMenu`'s view to the view hierarchy.